# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project_Tracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner and trying to run simple code and I encounter the warning No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project_Tracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring

Any help would be great! Thanks!!!

[image: Project Structure added]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Project Tracker</display-name>

    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-      class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

spring-dispatcher.xml
----------------------

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.projecttrack" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
       <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
       <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

**AnnotationController.java**

```
    package com.projecttracker.controllers;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class AnnotationController {


        @RequestMapping(value="/LoginPage.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getLoginRequest(){

            ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("LoginPage");
            model.addObject("projectTitle","Project Track");
            return model;

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/LoginSuccess.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView getLoginResponse(@RequestParam("userName") String name,
                                             @RequestParam("passWord") String password){

            UserInfo userinfo1=new UserInfo();
            userinfo1.setuserName(name);
            userinfo1.setpassWord(password);

            ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("LoginSuccess");
            model.addObject("userinfo1",userinfo1);
            return model;           
        }
    }
```

**UserInfo.java (POJO class)**

```
package com.projecttracker.controllers;

public class UserInfo {

    private String userName;
    private String passWord;


    public String getuserName(){

        return userName;
    }

    public void setuserName(String name){

        userName=name;
    }

    public String getpassWord(){

        return passWord;

    }

    public void setpassWord(String password){

        passWord=password;

    }
}
```

**LoginPage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<h2>${projectTitle}</h2>
<body>


  <form action="/ProjectTrack/LoginSuccess.html" method="post">
   <fieldset>

    <h3>Sign In</h3>

    User name: 

    <input type="text" name="userName"><br><br>

    Password:

    <input type="text" name="passWord"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>

   </fieldset>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginSuccess.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Project Track</title>
</head>
<body>

    <br>
   ${userinfo1.userName}<br>
   ${userinfo1.passWord}<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your project structure?

Comment: have you tried going to the URLs defined in the controller's `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: Hey Ramesh, below is my project structure

Comment: Project structure added and yes I tried going into the urls defined in the controller and I get a 404 error. I even tried re-installing tomcat. I am using spring current version 4.2.6 release and tomcat 7 with jdk 8, Is this ok,

Comment: spring-dispatcher.xml also added. Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `/` to 
`@RequestMapping(value="/LoginPage.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)` like:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/", "/LoginPage.html"), method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Or you can create a `index` page or `welcome` page in root path. What you met is just there is not a controller method which is mapped to `/`.

Comment: Thanks it worked!.... I just changed the @RequestMapping to @RequestMapping(value= ("/"), method=RequestMethod.GET)